# findViewById(R.id.list) is not resolving?

Tags: java, android

findViewById(R.id.list) is not resolving?

I'm getting the below error message:
R.id.list cannot be resolved.

I'm extending ListActivity and in the layout I have ListView android:id="@android:id/list"

```
    public class Results extends ListActivity {
    static final String TAG = "Results";
    ListView m_lv;
    List<Map<String, String>> m_dataList = null;

    ListView lv;
    SimpleAdapter m_adapter;
    ProgressDialog m_dialog;
    AsyncTask<String, String, String> bg;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listviewparent);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv = getListView();
```

Below is the listviewparent.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout style="@style/TitleBar">
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_home"
            android:src="@drawable/title_home"
            android:onClick="onClickHome" />
        <ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
        <TextView style="@style/TitleBarText" />
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
            android:src="@drawable/title_about"
            android:onClick="onClickAbout" />
        <ImageButton style="@style/TitleBarAction"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_search"
            android:src="@drawable/title_search"
            android:onClick="onClickSearch" />
    </LinearLayout>
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="0px"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: comment lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);   and check whether lv=getListView() returns list?

Comment: You don't have a ListView with that id in your layout. Try `android.R.id.list` instead.

Answer (score 5):

For R.id.list the namespace must be `android.R` but for your view parent your `R` is one of your program namespaces. Just add `android.` to the beginning of `R.id.list` to fix the namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.list)
```